# How to call the constructor in this class.

Tags: c++, constructor

The following is a made-up example, but representative of a code sample I am working on.

How do we call the constructor of the class `test` here?

```
class Test
{
public:
  Test(vector<double>* pt)
  {
    ptv = pt;
  }
  vector<double>* ptv;

};



class container
{

public:
  container(double a, double b)
  {
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
    // How to call the construtor of ct_ptv here? 
  }
  vector<double> v;
  Test        ct_ptv;
};
```

In words, I have two classes. One of them is called container whose instantiations
contain a vector of size 2. The same 
class will also have a class called `Test` which would contain a pointer 
to the vector `v`.

How do I call the constructor of `ct_ptv` here?

Comment: _`// How to call the construtor of ct_ptv here? `_ You don't (can't) call it in the constructor body but need to initialize it in the member initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

```
class container
{
public:
    container(double a, double b) :
        v({ a, b }),
        ct_ptv(&v)
    {
    }
    vector<double> v;
    Test ct_ptv;
};
```

Comment: Sometimes you get a warning when you refer to members from the initializer list. I had this when I passed some pointer down to a base class. Check twice before you ignore the warning if you get it.

Comment: Note that the `v({ a, b })` syntax is only available in C++11 and later. Prior to C++11, you will have to stick with calling `v.push_back()` in the constructor body. You can still initialize `ct_ptv` in the constructor's initialization list, though.

Comment: @BitTickler the warning you're referring to is probably about using a member variable before it's initialized. If `v` and `ct_ptv` were switched in this example (in the class definition, not in the initializer list) that warning would appear. Data members are always initialized in the order they appear in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
class container
{
public:
  container(double a, double b)
      : ct_ptv(&v)
  {
    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
  }
  vector<double> v;
  Test        ct_ptv;
};
```